# ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-auth

We are using ejabberd24.02 version. Ejabberd is frequently disconnected with Mysql.

> 2024-03-19 05:27:46.126230+00:00 [warning]
> <0.3616.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.127434+00:00 [warning] <0.18119.1>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection
> failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.127943+00:00 [warning] <0.3615.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.129085+00:00 [warning] <0.3617.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.130374+00:00 [warning] <0.18111.1>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection
> failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds

We are using external authentication python file. Sometime login is not working and get the below error. But this not happen for all time.

> 2024-03-19 05:27:38.138391+00:00 [info]
> <0.18116.39>@ejabberd_c2s:bind/2:470 (tls|<0.18116.39>) Opened c2s
> session for username@xmpp-beta.chat.com/1709276184348 2024-03-19
> 05:27:39.924430+00:00 [error] <0.18093.39>@extauth:handle_info/2:162
> External authentication program 'python3 /opt/ejabberd/login.py' has
> terminated unexpectedly (pid=1059731), restarting via supervisor...
> 2024-03-19 05:27:39.924713+00:00 [error]
> <0.2221.0>@supervisor:do_restart/3:742 SUPERVISOR REPORT:
> supervisor: {local,'extauth_pool_xmpp-beta.chat.com'}
> errorContext: child_terminated
> reason: normal
> offender: [{pid,<0.18093.39>},
> {id,'extauth_pool_xmpp-beta.chat.com_1'},
> {mfargs,{extauth,start_link,
> ['extauth_pool_xmpp-beta.chat.com_1',
> "python3 /opt/ejabberd/Login.py"]}},
> {restart_type,permanent},
> {significant,false},
> {shutdown,5000},
> {child_type,worker}]
>
> 2024-03-19 05:27:46.126230+00:00 [warning]
> <0.3616.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.127434+00:00 [warning] <0.18119.1>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection
> failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.127943+00:00 [warning] <0.3615.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.129085+00:00 [warning] <0.3617.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds 2024-03-19 05:27:46.130374+00:00 [warning] <0.18111.1>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:491 odbc connection
> failed:
> ** Reason: {"IM002",0,
> "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified Connection to database failed."}
> ** Retry after: 30 seconds